# Why rewrite doesn't work in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following server configuration:

```
server {
    listen       7777;
    server_name  localhost;

    rewrite ^/standardlib/(.*)$ /standardlib/src/main/webapp/$1 last;

    location / {
        root   D:\Projects\gibr;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://172.22.90.61:8008;
    }
}
```

I have the following link for the resource:

```
http://localhost:7777/standardlib/resources/css/standardlib.css
```

But the file is actually inside:

```
/standardlib/src/main/webapp/resources/css/standardlib.css
```

So I'm trying to rewrite the url:

```
rewrite ^/standardlib/(.*)$ /standardlib/src/main/webapp/$1 last;
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. I added logging:

```
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
rewrite_log     on;
```

But there's no information in the error log about rewriting.

I've checked the regex with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dX7pO3/1), and seems to be capturing the correct group.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

It's actually working, I've added `log_not_found on;`, but for some reason it tries to find the following file:

```
`D:\webservers\nginx/html\standardlib\src\main\webapp\bootstrap.js`
```

instead of

```
`D:\projects\gibr\standardlib\src\main\webapp\bootstrap.js`
```

Here is what I've got in the log:

```
15128#7720: *1 "^/standardlib/(.*)$" matches "/standardlib/bootstrap.js"
15128#7720: *1 rewritten data: "\standardlib\src\main\webapp\bootstrap.js"
15128#7720: *1 CreateFile() "D:\webservers\nginx/html\standardlib\src\main\webapp\bootstrap.js" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Try to turn on `log_not_found` (http://nginx.org/r/log_not_found)

Comment: Your root seems to suggest you are on windows. Now you have a combination of forward and backslashes in your paths. Perhaps that's the problem. See http://serverfault.com/questions/49414/how-do-i-specify-windows-file-paths-in-nginx

Comment: @AlexeyTen, thanks, it started to log, please see my update

Comment: @JayMcTee, thanks, please see my update, there seems to be indeed a problem with slashes. But also the rewrite rule forms incorrect path from the root

Comment: @Maximus and what is real path to your file?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, it's `D:\projects\gibr\standardlib\src\main\webapp\bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are mixing a Windows root path with backslashes, with Unix style forward slahes.

See comments here: [How do I specify Windows file paths in nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/49414/how-do-i-specify-windows-file-paths-in-nginx)

I'm no Windows sysadmin, but it seems you need to use relative paths like ../ to get your path complete and working.

Also see: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/172663